# a JS closure query

Tags: javascript

I am a C++ ( Qt ) developer and know JS a bit. I am not able to understand a part of below code. Can you please help me with this?

```
function augment(withFn) {
    var name, fn;
    for (name in window) {
        fn = window[name];

        if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    // **Not able to understand below code.**
            window[name] = (function(name, fn) {
                var args = arguments;
                return function() {
                    withFn.apply(this, args);
                    fn.apply(this, arguments);

                }
            })(name, fn);
    // **In above code I understood everything else except this last line. 
    // Why whole function is in circular bracket? Why it ends with (name, fn);
    // What is the meaning of this?
        }
    }
}

augment(function(name, fn) {
    console.log("calling " + name);
});
```

Comment: @Quentin: actually it's not only about the syntax, but also about why it's used there

Comment: +1 to All, @zerkms 's examples are really good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self executed anonymous function is a common way to solve an issue with closures in a loops.

So it's practically an anonymous function that is declared and executed immediately with passed parameters.

Actually `name` parameter is useless there, since it's not used, but if you didn't do the trick - then only the last `fn` parameter would be passed as a reference.

The demonstration of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/nfjtn/

The solution (using the self-executing anonymous function): http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/nfjtn/1/

Comment: One question, what about efficiency? Wouldn't it be faster to define a function variable once and just `apply` it in each loop?

Comment: I'm sure it would be faster, yes

Comment: @zerkms, Thanks a lot for answer with examples. If possible, Please provide me your prefered link to learn these kind of JS concepts.

Comment: @SunnyShah: actually I don't know any particular. Once while ago I experienced the issue - I've googled a bit about, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all:

`(function f(param) { alert(param); })("Hello world");`
defines the function and immediately executes it.

```
function f(param) { alert("This: = " + this + ". Param=" + param); }
f.apply(window, "Hello world");
```

Calls the function f *in the context of* `window` (that is the function 'thinks' it belongs to the `window` object) with params `params`

`function(param)` return a reference to an anonymous function. That is:

`var f = function(param) {...}; f("Hello world");` is similar to:

```
(function(param){...})("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression in parentheses (what you call "circular brackets") is an anonymous function. `(name, fn)` at the end of it means that the function should be called with those arguments, and the return value is assigned to `window[name]`. It's approximately equivalent to:

```
tempfn = function(name, fn) { /* body */ };
window[name] = tempfn(name, fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually in C you would have the definition (and maybe declaration)

```
int anon(string name, void* function) {
}
```

and the call to the function

```
anon(name, function);
```

The part inside the circular brackets is the declaration of an anonymous function; which is immediately called with the `(name, fn)` parameters.

Think of it as (NOTE: may JS is a little rusty so some syntax error is possible)

```
 var fn2 = (function(name, fn) {
    var args = arguments;
    return function() {
      withFn.apply(this, args);
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
   });
```

And, in the loop

```
 window[name] = fn2.apply(name, fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to circumvent here is referencing `name` and `fn` in your loop afterwards. If you just did `window[name] = function () { alert(name); }` all your assigned functions would always use the value that `name` was last set to, not what it was when that particular function was defined in your loop. To get around this you create a function that is called immediately with the correct values and that way protects them in a new closure. You can read more about it in this SO-question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)